# concat php strings; using . operator or double quotes

Tags: php, string

> Edit - My question is not stricktly limited to preformance, I would also like to know the pitfalls of each and if there is a condition where one **should** be used over the other.

Which is better to use to concat a string in PHP?

Option A: Use the . operator to concat the strings

```
$string1 = "hello ";
$string2 = $string1 . "world !";
```

Option B: Use double quotes

```
$string1 = "hello ";
$string2 = "$string1 world !";
```

I realize that both will in fact do the same thing, and in my personal development I prefer to use the . operator.
My question only arises because i've read that the . operator forces php to re-concatenate with each new string, so in the example:

```
$string1 = "hello ";
$string2 = "world";
$string3 = $string1.$string2." !";
```

would actually run slower than

```
$stirng1 = "hello";
$string2 = "world";
$string3 = "$string1 $string2 !";
```

Reference: [PHP Language Operators > Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Have you run into any performance problems on your server? Use whichever is clearest to *read* for the next programmer after you!

Comment: I would imagine concatenating would be faster because the latter required to parse the text and look for $ expression or use eval() which is probably far slower.

Comment: Actually if you read the reference the author says that concat is faster. "I ran the follow script and found that using "$var" was 'mostly' slower than using ' '.$var"

Comment: Wouldn't the double quote version add an additional space in the result? (If you produce HTML, this might not be visible, though.)

Comment: @Kerrek SB, I have, and I am seeing the same results as expected on my test server.

Comment: @rlemon: Interesting - I'd be curious to hear if changing the string concatenation helps!

Comment: Unless you're running a Facebook-sized operation, you're wasting far more time on playing with these micro-optimizations than the optimizations would ever save you later on.

Comment: @Marc B, My question was generic. I am not applying this to any specific case right now. I have always been curious and when a _google search_ did not return a clear answer I turned to a group of my peers. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think before you start worrying about it, you need to see if it is even worth thinking about. I did think about it, and wrote the following tiny script and ran it to see what the benchmarks were like.

For each loop, I made 100,000 passes. Now I didn't print my strings anywhere so if the PHP optimizer takes all of my work away because of that, then I apologize. However looking at these results, you are looking at a difference of about 0.00001 second for each.

Before you optimize for anything other than readability, use a profiler and see where your hotspots are. If you run tens of millions of concatenations, then you may have an argument. But with 1000, you are still talking about a difference of 0.01 seconds. I'm sure you could save more than 0.01 seconds just by optimizing SQL queries and the like.

My evidence is below....

Here's what I ran:

```
<?php
for($l = 0; $l < 5; $l++)
  {
    echo "Pass " .$l. ": \n";
    $starta = microtime(1);
    for( $i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
      {
    $a = md5(rand());
    $b = md5(rand());
    $c = "$a $b".' Hello';
      }
    $enda = microtime(1);

    $startb = microtime(1);
    for( $i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
      {
    $a = md5(rand());
    $b = md5(rand());
    $c = $a . ' ' . $b . ' Hello';
      }
    $endb = microtime(1);


    echo "\tFirst method: " . ($enda - $starta) . "\n";
    echo "\tSecond method: " . ($endb - $startb) . "\n";
  }
```

Here are the results:

```
Pass 0: 
    First method: 1.3060460090637
    Second method: 1.3552670478821
Pass 1: 
    First method: 1.2648279666901
    Second method: 1.2579910755157
Pass 2: 
    First method: 1.2534148693085
    Second method: 1.2467019557953
Pass 3: 
    First method: 1.2516458034515
    Second method: 1.2479140758514
Pass 4: 
    First method: 1.2541329860687
    Second method: 1.2839770317078
```

Comment: That is a very good example. I am also looking for information on both methods and which **should be used when/or where**

Comment: Honestly, I would write the code that is most obvious to other developers. My personal preference is concatenation (`$a . ' ' . $b`) verses interpolation (`"$a $b"`).

Comment: Ok, I agree there. No one has answered my question yet though. **Is there a condition where one should be used over the other**, or is it simply a matter of preference?

Comment: To that end, I would say yes there is a condition, and the condition is: use whatever is more readable. And if that is at odds with speed, in the extreme case, then optimize for speed. Remember that you, or someone else, will have to come back to maintain the code.  I know it's a snarky response, but there will truly be bigger things to optimize on than speed in this sense. Optimize for cleanliness, and future maintenance. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Concatenation is almost always faster than interpolation, but the difference is rarely significant enough to warrant caring. That said, I prefer concatenation because it allows easier editing when (for example) you want to change a string to a method or function call. I.e., from:

```
$s1 = 'this ' . $thing . ' with a thing';
```

To:

```
$s1 = 'this ' . blarg($thing) . ' with a thing';
```

Edit: When I say, "Concatenation is almost always faster than interpolation," what I mean is, I have actually benchmarked many various forms of it, and I'm not just guessing, or reiterating somebody else's post. It's easy to do, try it.

Comment: Could this possibly be a result of the environment? I have run the test posted here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php#71062 and I am seeing that interpolation runs slightly faster.

Comment: Sure, it could also change based on your OS, your PHP version, the length of your strings, the number of strings you're compiling, the humidity, and the phase of the moon. Which is why you should never ask anybody else what's faster, and always measure it yourself, with your code, on your hardware.

Comment: I updated my post, performance was one concern. Please read the edit above. Also, albeit correct, you didn't have to be so harsh. a simple 'yes' however.. would suffice.

Comment: No harshness intended, just trying to emphasize that you should get in the habit of doing performance testing yourself because so many different things affect the outcome.

Comment: If you read my comment above; I have run a test, and my results conflict your own. Which is why I asked how environment would affect such a basic operation.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to put a significantly large number of strings together all at once, consider [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$result = implode('', $array_of_strings);
```

For insignificant numbers of strings, which method you use does not have noticeable differences.

Comment: String concatenation is faster than the array method in all cases.